# How to call a function from SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have function that have been colled in stored procedure.
The function returns a table and have to fill another table.
Maybe this queistion might be seems a little naive but im a newer in T-SQL.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the function as though it was a table. You can:

```
Select * From dbo.MyFunction()
```

If you need to pass a value from the outer query into the UDF, use [Cross Apply](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/nakul/archive/2011/04/28/cross-apply-underappreciated-features-of-microsoft-sql-server.aspx)

like this:

```
 Select * From sys.dm_exec_requests ser 
 Cross Apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ser.sql_handle)
```